# secureTextEntry doesn't hide the text of my UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to hide the text of a UITextView, used as a password entry, using dots instead of the actual text. This text view is called TV_Password.
When its empty, the text should not be hidden and should be replaced by the string "Password"

I found on the net that the solution would be to change the following property to true.

```
self.TV_Password.secureTextEntry = true
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't hide my text.
I moved the modifications to textViewShouldBeginEditing instead of textViewDidBeginEditing, as advised to people having this kind of issue, but it still doesn't work.
I haves various breakpoints telling me the instruction IS really done, but nothing happens..

Any idea .?

```
//MARK: TextViews editing

func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    if (textView == self.TV_Password){
        if (self.TV_Password.text == "Password"){
            //empty text
            self.TV_Password.text = ""
            //enable secured text
            self.TV_Password.secureTextEntry = true

        }
    }
    return true
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if (textView == self.TV_Password) {
        //if password empty
        if (self.TV_Password.text == ""){
            //disable secured text
            self.TV_Password.secureTextEntry = false
            //fill with the word "Password"
            self.TV_Password.text = "Password"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UITextView` doesn't have a secure entry mode.

Comment: You will want to use a `UITextField` if you want that functionality.

Comment: It's weird that Xcode knows such a method and auto complete..even for a UITextView..
Anyway, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER : 
UITextView doesn't have a secure entry mode, use a UITextField instead.
Thanks a lot!